# javascript/jquery error "invalid object initializer"

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, exception

I'm calling a function like this:

```
myfunc($tab, {'top-left', 'bottom-left'}, defaults.tabRounded);
```

The function definition is:

```
function myfunc(obj, properties, value) {
```

Yet I get the error "Invalid object initializer". Is this because of the json argument? Or something else?

Comment: What do you think JSON is exactly? There is no JSON in your code snippet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
myfunc($tab, {'top-left', 'bottom-left'}, defaults.tabRounded);
```

With

```
myfunc($tab, ['top-left', 'bottom-left'], defaults.tabRounded);
```

`{'top-left', 'bottom-left'}` is not an object, but `{'top-left': 0, 'bottom-left': 10}` is an object. I assumed you might have wanted an array instead of an object.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript objects are key/value pairs:

```
{
    'top-left': 333,
    'bottom-left': 444
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_Object_Initializers

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to pass array, not object to the function:

```
myfunc($tab, ['top-left', 'bottom-left'], defaults.tabRounded);
```

Otherwise if you want to pass object you need to specify values for the keys. Something like:

```
myfunc($tab, {'top-left': 100, 'bottom-left': 100}, defaults.tabRounded);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the properties like { x: 'foo', y: 'bar' }, as these are always key-value pairs.